# Animate the movement of a marker iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to animate the movement of a GMSmarker (or any object for that sake), between 2 points.
(Just to clarify this is using either Apple Maps or Google Maps)

So I would have the initalPoint, and the newPoint, and it would animate the icon that is marking 'position' from intialPoint to newPoint.

I have rigorously searched the Google Maps SDK myself but couldn't find anything that would do it.

Can anyone provide and code samples/tutorials on how to do such a thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now have this working. The way to do this is to simple update the location of a MKPointAnnotation (using apple maps)

In swift it goes:

```
var thePoint : MKPointAnnotation()
thePoint.setCoordinates([CLLocationCoordainte2D variable goes here])
```

Do this multiple times a second and it appears to smoothly move.

Answer (score 0):

You could overlay your own custom "marker" and animate it using `UIView` animations. For example, the following code would move a red square from `pointA` to `pointB`.

```
- (void)moveMarker
{
    CGPoint pointA = CGPointMake(30, 40);
    CGPoint pointB = CGPointMake(120,65);

    UIView *marker = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:
                                       CGRectMake(pointA.x, pointA.y, 10, 10)];
    marker.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

    [mapViewIWantToAddAMarkerTo addSubview:marker];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:5 animations:^{
        marker.frame = CGRectMake(pointB.x, pointB.y, 10, 10);
    }];
}
```

Comment: This solution did not result in anything :(